# Function with argument to a NSInvocation method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsinvocation

I have a controller view who is using thoses 2 functions:

```
[appDelegate getFichesInfo:[[self.fichesCategory idModuleFiche] intValue] ]; //first function
self.fiche = (Fiche *)[appDelegate.fichesInfo objectAtIndex:0];


[appDelegate getFichesVisuels:[[self.fiche idFiche] intValue] ];  //second function not working
self.fiche = (Fiche *)[appDelegate.fichesInfo objectAtIndex:0];
```

So in my ressourceManager, here is the 2nd function in details:

```
- (void)getFichesVisuels:(int)value {

    fichesVisuels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_reset(getFichesVisuelsStatement);


        sqlite3_bind_int(getFichesVisuelsStatement, 1,  value);

        while(sqlite3_step(getFichesVisuelsStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


            NSString *aTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getFichesVisuelsStatement , 7)];
            NSString *aLpath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getFichesVisuelsStatement , 8)];

            Visuel *visuel = [[Visuel alloc] initWithName:aTitle lpath:aLpath];

            [fichesVisuels addObject:visuel];
        }

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

The problem is that the 2nd function is not working (librairies routine called out of sequence) because I am already calling the 1st function in the same way (I wanna be able to execute many query using arguments in the same times). I heard that using NSInvocation can be the solution to this problem, but I don't know how to turn my code using NSInvocation.
Someone can help me?

Best Regards,

Comment: What isn't working and what makes you think that NSInvocation is going to fix it in any way?

Comment: In fact this function is working but only if I use only this one in my View controller but I already use another function first and after that this one don't work. Here is my function: --------- [appDelegate getFichesInfo:[[self.fichesCategory idModuleFiche] intValue] ];
self.fiche = (Fiche *)[appDelegate.fichesInfo objectAtIndex:0]; --------
after that I use the one I put in my question ------ [appDelegate getFichesInfo:[[self.fichesCategory idModuleFiche] intValue] ];
 self.fiche = (Fiche *)[appDelegate.fichesInfo objectAtIndex:0];-------
You can see that I reuse one argument from the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you could be having is that your prepared statement is invalid after `sqlite3_close`.  You need to create a new prepared statement each time you open the database.

1. Open the database with `sqlite3_open`.
2. Prepare the statement with `sqlite3_prepare` and friends.
3. Bind with `sqlite3_bind`.
4. Step with `sqlite3_step`.
5. Afterwards, ensure you call `sqlite3_finalize`.
6. Close the database with `sqlite3_close`.

You can't just reset the statement, because that statement was prepared for a different database handle.

#### NB

I'm not too familiar with SQLite.

Comment: sorry I forget to say that all my statements are already prepared when I initialize the database, everything is compiled before to faster access. ---------
const char *getFichesVisuelsSQL = GET_FICHES_VISUELS_SQL;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, getFichesVisuelsSQL, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
getFichesVisuelsStatement = compiledStatement; -------

Comment: I didn't use the sqlite3_ finalize I will try it. Do I have to do that everytime?

Comment: Each time you open the database, you must prepare your statements again, because that prepared statement is specific to the database you opened. Also, you only called `sqlite3_finalize` to balance the `sqlite3_prepare`, similar to `retain` and `release`.

Comment: If you close your database with `sqlite3_close`, all prepared statements that were created using that database handle are now invalid.

Comment: But all of my functions are working, the statement already prepared and compiled I just have to reuse functions like that.
the problem is that in the same controller view I'm calling 2 differents function and the second one call an argument on the first one.